# Time series data: How to find the mean repetition rate of a value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, statistics

I used Matlab to analyse the time series data of global surface temperature. After analysing the time series data of the global surface temperature, I found that certain temperature values have reappeared over the course of a certain duration which I grouped and then used gscatter function to plot on the scatter plot!

I want some help to find what is the rate at which Earth's temperature hits 5.6 degrees? My intention is to find the rate at which this event is occurring so that I can statistically say when will be the next expected occurrence of the event in the near future!

**Results:**

[image: scatter plot showing temperature range in groups]

**Data:**

[image: years that had a temperature of 5.6 degrees]

```matlab
Data = [ 1750 5.6
         1765 5.6
         1774 5.6
         1777 5.6
         1786 5.6
         1800 5.6
         1818 5.6
         1821 5.6
         1847 5.6
         1870 5.6
         1887 5.6
         1897 5.6
         1916 5.6
         1920 5.6
         1961 5.6
         1978 5.6
         1991 5.6 ];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!   Please familiarize yourself with this FAQ and repost your question -- How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using MATLAB could be the following (code snippet). You determine the intervals between the years with 5.6 degrees. Then, you just calculate the mean and standard deviation for these intervals. I can't tell if that is a meaningful (statistical) measure, but you can calculate any other measure on the before-mentioned intervals. The boxplot just visualizes, that the distribution of the intervals is kinda broad.

```matlab
% Input.
Data = [ 1750 5.6
         1765 5.6
         1774 5.6
         1777 5.6
         1786 5.6
         1800 5.6
         1818 5.6
         1821 5.6
         1847 5.6
         1870 5.6
         1887 5.6
         1897 5.6
         1916 5.6
         1920 5.6
         1961 5.6
         1978 5.6
         1991 5.6 ];

% Calculate intervals between years.
intYear = diff(Data(:, 1));

% Boxplot (requires Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox).
% Mean and standard deviation of intervals in title.
figure(1);
boxplot(intYear);
xlim([0 2]);
title(['Mean: ' num2str(mean(intYear)) ' years, Standard deviation: ' num2str(std(intYear)) ' years']);
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you alot.. It worked! I have plotted different temperature ranges on the same box plot!